# AngularJS collapse directive. Collapse all but self

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm struggling to find the best solution for a collapse/expand directive that behaves like an accordion, ie. only one collapse/expand directive on the page must be open at any one time.

What is the best way to go about this, and get an expanding directive to tell the other directives to collapse? Can I use an isolated scope, a parent controller, broadcast events? Basically I'm having difficulties wrapping my head around inter-directive communication.

I know that there are accordion directives available, but I want to learn building directives myself. Thanks.

Comment: Considering the [angularui-bootstrap-accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) is clean/elegant, yet STILL required a few hundred lines of code and an understanding of the complexities of directives, this might be a rough directive to start with.  I would start by just trying to have one directive do some easy manipulation of another. Background colors or something.

Comment: Good point, though there is a lot of functionality that I don't need in that directive. I've answered with what I came up with; essentially using $broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using $broadcast from a parent controller. The expanding directive asks the parent controller to broadcast a collapseChange event, which all directives listen for.

Parent controller

```
$scope.broadcastCollapseChange = function (id) {
        $scope.$broadcast('collapseChange', { 'id': id});
    };
```

Directive

```
            scope.collapsed = true;
            var onCollapseChange = function (v) {
                if (scope.collapsed == false)
                    scope.$parent.broadcastCollapseChange(scope.$id);
            }
            scope.$watch('collapsed', onCollapseChange);

            scope.$on('collapseChange', function (event, args) {
                if (scope.collapsed == false && args.id != scope.$id)
                    scope.collapsed = true;
            });
```

Currently I have to use $parent in the directive to get the parent controller, which is not very elegant. Is there any way I can get around this?